# How to close dialog window from viewmodel (Caliburn+WPF)?

Tags: wpf, dialog, window, caliburn.micro

I have`ViewModel1` and View1 associated with it. I start dialog window from `ViewModel2` (some another viewmodel) using `IWindowManager` object. The code from `ViewModel2` class:

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(new ViewModel());
```

So, I have Dialog Window with View1 user control.

My answer is next - I can close that dialog window using red close button, but how to close it using my specific button (contained in `View1` user control), something like "Cancel" button with close command (`Command={Binding CancelCommand}`), `CancelCommand` of course is contained in `ViewModel1` class.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's even easier if your view model extends `Caliburn.Micro.Screen`:

```cs
TryClose();
```

Comment: Well it does close the whole app only if you're trying to close the main application window.

Comment: Hi @MichalT, I am showing dialog like await _dialogManager.ShowDialogAsync(item, new List<DialogResult>() { DialogResult.Cancel });  and I want to close it using timer. Inside tick event when I am using this.DialogHost().TryClose(DialogResult.Cancel); then this.DialogHost() is giving null.

Answer (score 11):

You can get the current view (in your case the dialog window) with implementing the `IViewAware` interface on your ViewModel. Then you can call `Close` on the the view (the `Window` created as the dialog) when your command is executed.

The easiest why is to derive from `ViewAware`:

```
public class DialogViewModel : ViewAware
{
    public void ExecuteCancelCommand()
    {
        (GetView() as Window).Close();
    }
}
```

If you are not allowed to derive you can implement it yourself:

```
public class DialogViewModel : IViewAware
{
    public void ExecuteCancelCommand()
    {
        dialogWindow.Close();
    }

    private Window dialogWindow;
    public void AttachView(object view, object context = null)
    {
        dialogWindow = view as Window;
        if (ViewAttached != null)
            ViewAttached(this, 
               new ViewAttachedEventArgs(){Context = context, View = view});
    }

    public object GetView(object context = null)
    {
        return dialogWindow;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ViewAttachedEventArgs> ViewAttached;
}
```

Note: I've used Caliburn.Micro 1.3.1 for my sample.

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner way (Subject of personal taste) that I use alot is to use the IResult pattern, this way you abstract the Window implemenation

Viewmodel

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> CloseMe()
{
    yield return new CloseResult();
}
```

Result code

```
public class CloseResult : Result
{
    public override void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        var window = Window.GetWindow(context.View);
        window.Close();            

        base.Execute(context);
    }
}

public abstract class Result : IResult
{
    public virtual void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        OnCompleted(this, new ResultCompletionEventArgs());
    }

    protected virtual void OnCompleted(object sender, ResultCompletionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Completed != null)
            Completed(sender, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<ResultCompletionEventArgs> Completed;
}
```

**edit (Only needed for IoC)**: If you wanna take it a step further you do a base class for all screens

```
public abstract class ShellPresentationModel : Screen
{
    public ShellPresentationModel(IResultFactory resultFactory)
    {
        Result = resultFactory;
    }

    public IResultFactory Result { get; private set; }
}
```

This way you can inject dependencies with a IoC much easier, then your VIewmodel close method will look like this

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> CloseMe()
{
    yield return Result.Close();
}
```

An example on a IResult that uses dependency can be

```
public class ShowDialogResult<TModel> : Result
{
    private readonly IWindowManager windowManager;
    private readonly TModel model;
    private Action<TModel> configure;

    public ShowDialogResult(IWindowManager windowManager, TModel model)
    {
        this.windowManager = windowManager;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public IResult Configure(Action<TModel> configure)
    {
       this.configure = configure;
       return this;
    }

    public override void Execute(ActionExecutionContext context)
    {
        if(configure != null)
            configure(model);

        windowManager.ShowDialog(model);

        base.Execute(context);
    }
}
```

**edit** Just noticed that i forgot to add an example of the above IoC exmaple, here goes
With a child IoC container pattern it would look like this

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> ShowDialog()
{
    yield return Result.ShowDialog<MyViewModel>();
}
```

Without a child container pattern you would need to inject parent dependeync into the child manually

```
    yield return Result.ShowDialog<MyViewModel>().Configure(m => m.SomeData = this.SomeData);
```