# How to use CanClose()?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to close my Caliburn window but unsure how to use it.

CanClose expects one item in it's parameter
Parameter 1 - Action callback

I'm simply trying to use the function this.CanClose() but unsure what goes inbetween the parenthesis

```
public void closeWindow()
{
    this.CanClose();
}

public override void CanClose(Action<bool> callback)
{
    base.CanClose(callback);
}
```

Comment: You need to show the code

Comment: Sorrry about that, I thought it would be trivial. Updated and I hope it makes it more understandable =)

Comment: Look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090584/how-to-close-dialog-window-from-viewmodel-caliburnwpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback like this:

```
CanClose( p => {  DoSomething(); } );
```

Comment: Can you give me a basic DoSomething(); Not quite sure how to create and Action<bool> function.

Comment: it would simply be... private void DoSomething() {}

Answer (score 0):

You should insert callback method as parameter.

```
this.CanClose(MyMethod);
```